# Mysql: How to optimize deleting thousands of rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have hundred thousand rows in my table and I want to delete with condition  It took 15 min but still not done? It's just a plane table no related model. Its a chunk of almost 200k rows that I want to remove I need to specify which needed to remove so I need to use condition If I can just truncate. Is there any way to handle this, I'm using laravel

```
Details::where('file_name_belongs',$file_name)->delete();
```

Comment: If you know how to group the rows you will delete later, using [partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) will massively improve delete performance.

Comment: Is there an index on `file_name_belongs`?

Comment: @MarkBaker No its a normal varchar column that I created to Identify what date it made to tell which rows need to delete

Comment: If you are deleting based on the age of the records, you really should look at partitions. You can create a partition for each day (or whatever), and dropping the oldest partition and rolling a new one will be almost as fast as truncate.

Comment: As you're using that column for a selection criteria, and it's unindexed, then the database is having to run a full table scan, looking through every record in that table; that will make it slow for a start